# Limit of $(X' (\Delta + \varepsilon I_n)^{-1} X)^{-1}$ with $\Delta$ an $n \times n$ diagonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, quadratic-forms, symmetric-matrices

The question is pretty much in the title; $X$ is an $n\times r$ matrix with $n>r$, and of course I am asking for the limit in $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

The interesting case is the case in which there are some zeroes on the diagonal of $\Delta$; if there aren’t any, it is straightforward.

I am interested both by a nice expression of the limit and by a way to compute it numerically without rounding issues.

**Example**

With $X = \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 3 \end{matrix}\right]$ and $\Delta = \left[\begin{matrix} 8 & 0& 0\\ 0& 2 &0 \\ 0& 0& \varepsilon \end{matrix}\right]$ it is easy to see that 
$$ (X' \Delta^{-1} X) =
 \left[\begin{matrix} 5/8 + 1/\varepsilon & 9/8 + 3/\varepsilon \\ 
        9/8 + 3/\varepsilon & 17/8 + 9/\varepsilon\end{matrix}\right] $$
and its determinant is $1/\varepsilon + 1/16$, hence the limit in $\varepsilon =0$ is
$$\left[\begin{matrix} 9 & -3 \\ -3 & 1 \\ \end{matrix}\right].$$

Comment: $X'$ means transpose? (I'm more familiar with $X^T$.)

Comment: Yes, and $r<n$!

Comment: I'll do it later, I am on my phone and cooking a pizza right now!

Comment: I've edited it accordingly.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for this.

Comment: Isn't $x'Ax$ supposed to be a scalar whatever the matrix $A$ is?

Comment: @StubbornAtom $X$ is a matrix here, not a vector

Comment: But a vector can be thought of as a row/column matrix.

Comment: @StubbornAtom so if r = 1 you get a scalar.

Comment: Seeing the quadratic form tag, that's what I thought.

Comment: @StubbornAtom This tag is here because the limit matrix is symmetric and defines a quadratic form

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  In the main text, you mentioned that “$X$  is an $n\times r$ matrix with $n<r$, but then you gave an example of $X$ being $3\times 2$.  Is $n < r$ important here?

Comment: @Guangliang it's a typo, sorry. You need r < n to get a full rank r x r matrix when $\varepsilon>0$.